# Change the location of the cover image

Tags: graphics, alignment

I just downloaded this template from the internet:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large\bf\MakeUppercase}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{\Large\bf\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %control de tamaño de papel y márgenes
\usepackage{graphicx} %para poder incluir figuras 
\usepackage{siunitx} %para notación científica
\usepackage{float} %complemento para figura
\usepackage{import} %para poder dividir el texto en varios archivos
\usepackage{natbib} %para la bibliografía
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing %Control del espacio entre lineas

%Hoja de la portada
\title{
    \vspace{-3.0cm}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{images/uoc.jpg}\\
    \vspace{3cm}
    %{\Large Seminario Superior en Sistemas}\\
    {\Large \textbf{TÍTULO DEL TRABAJO DE PREPARACIÓN DE SEMINARIO SUPERIOR}}\\
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\footnotesize \begin{flushright} \textit{Preparación de Seminario Superior parte de la actividad de} \\ \textit{Titulación para optar al Título profesional de Ingeniero} \\ \textit{en Información y Control de Gestión.} \end{flushright}}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\footnotesize \begin{flushright} \textit{\textbf{Profesor Guía: Nombre del profesor guía}} \end{flushright}}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\normalsize \textbf{Autor1\\Autor2}\\}
    \vspace{3.0cm}
    {\normalsize MES-AAA}
}
\author{} %dejar vacío
\date{} %dejar vacío
%----------

%Este bloque es para adaptar los nombres a español
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliografía}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Índice de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}
%----------

%Control del encabezado y pie de página
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%----------

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman} %comienza con número romano para las páginas
    \maketitle %agrega la portada al documento
    
    %se incluye lo contenido en resumen.tex
    %\include{resumen}
    
    %se incluye lo contenido en abstract.tex
    %\include{abstract}
    
    %se incluye lo contenido en agradecimientos.tex
    %\include{agradecimientos}
    
    %Estas 3 listas se crearán automáticamente, según los capítulos y secciones del documento 
    \tableofcontents    %crea la lista de contenidos
    \listoftables       %crea la lista de tablas
    \listoffigures      %crea la lista de figuras
    
    %incluye lo contenido en nomenclatura.tex
    % \include{nomenclatura}
    
    %incluye lo contenido en C1problema.tex
    \include{C1problema}
    
    %incluye lo contenido en C2marcoteorico.tex
    \include{C2marcoteorico}
    
    %incluye lo contenido en C3objetivos.tex
    \include{C3objetivos}
    
    %incluye lo contenido en C4conclusiones.tex
    \include{C4medologia}
    
    %incluye lo contenido en C5cartagantt.tex
    \include{C5cartagantt}
    
    %Generacion automatica de la lista de referencias 
    \bibliographystyle{apalike} %estilo APA
    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt} %estilo tipo EEE 
    \bibliography{references} %indica nombre del archivo de referencias
    
    
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly, except that the cover image is in the middle of the page, rather than at the top, pushing the rest of the text down.

I've tried different options but can't change it, I'm pretty new to tex, any ideas?

Edit:

This options here

```
\title{
    \vspace{-5.15cm}
```

Allowed me to change it.

However, at -5cm it's in the middle of the page, and at -5.15cm at the top. There's no middle ground.

Comment: That's because you are using negative argument. Use positive argument like `\vspace{2cm}` , changing the argument until you get where you want the figure.

Comment: Try to create a MWE (**minimal** working example), using an available image such as `example-image-a`, so that we can compile your code. With the `demo` option passed to `graphicx` I do not see any problem with vertical spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It works better if you use the environment `titlepage` after `\begin{document}` instead of `\maketitle`

I simplified your cover code to make it clearer . For this MWE  I kept only the packages needed for the cover but added the package `showframe` to show the margins.

[image: b]

Try this code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{showframe} % added to see the margins

\usepackage{mathptmx} % new fonts

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} %control de tamaño de papel y márgenes
\usepackage{graphicx} %para poder incluir figuras 

\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing %Control del espacio entre lineas

\author{} %dejar vacío
\date{} %dejar vacío
%----------

\begin{document}
    
        %Hoja de la portada
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{example-image-a} 
        
        \vspace*{2cm}
        
        \Large
        
        \textbf{%
            %   Seminario Superior en Sistemas \\
            TÍTULO DEL TRABAJO DE PREPARACIÓN DE SEMINARIO SUPERIOR}
        
        \vspace{2cm}
        
        \raggedleft \footnotesize 
        
        \emph{Preparación de Seminario Superior parte de la actividad de \\ 
            Titulación para optar al Título profesional de Ingeniero \\ 
            en Información y Control de Gestión.} 
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \bfseries
        \emph{Profesor Guía: Nombre del profesor guía}   
        \vspace{1.5cm} 
        
        \centering \normalsize 
        Autor1 \\ 
        Autor2 \\
        
        \vfill % push to the bottm
        \normalfont MES-AAAA
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman} %comienza con número romano para las páginas
    
\end{document}
```